# Change a dropdown menu array to a regular unordered list without jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a have a javascript array to make an image change when its name is selected (Waterfall, Sunset, White Tree). It is in the form of a dropdown menu right now, but I am wondering if I can change it to just a regular unordered list. I do not want to use jquery.

If the array cannot be changed to an unordered list, is there any other way to change the content in a div based on user interaction (onclick)?
i.e. three different links below an image. Once a link is clicked, a different image is 
loaded into the div.  This must be done with one function.

HTML

```
    <body>

    <img src="images/photo1.jpg" name="sunset">

    <ul> 
<select onClick=imageSwap(this) name=cached>
    <option value=image1>Sunset</option>
    <option value=image2>Waterfall</option>
    <option value=image3>White Tree</option>
</select>
    </ul>

    </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    if(document.images) {
    imageSwap = new Array();

    image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "images/photo1.jpg"
    image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "images/photo2.jpg"
    image3 = new Image()
    image3.src = "images/photo3.jpg"

    function imageSwap(list) {

    var img = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value; 

    document.sunset.src = eval(img + ".src");
    }
    }
```

Comment: How about a Google search? There are tons of such examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create links like these:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeImg('image1.jpg')">Image 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeImg('image2.jpg')">Image 2</a>
```

and a function:

```
function changeImg(src) {
  document.getElementById("imgId").src = src;
}
```

where *imgId* is the id of your `<img>` element.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WS2K/4/